# Get keymap that called function

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys

I am trying to write a function that can be used to make a keybinding "remember" the key sequence that led up to the function being called.

```
(defun modal-function (func)
  (funcall func)
  (set-transient-map (somehow-get-map-that-called-this-function)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x m h") (lambda () (interactive) (modal-function 'move-left)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x m j") (lambda () (interactive) (modal-function 'move-down)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x m k") (lambda () (interactive) (modal-function 'move-up)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x m l") (lambda () (interactive) (modal-function 'move-right)))
```

So running `C-x m h j k l` would result in `(move-left)` `(move-down)` `(move-up)` `(move-right)`.

I've read the [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881847/automatic-creation-of-repeatable-command) about making one command repeatable as well as smartrep.el but it is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use the hydra package for that?